# Exporting / Archiving changed files only in Git

Tags: git, export, archive, msysgit

Is there a simple way to export / archive only the changed files from a given commit or series of commits in git? I can't seem to find clear instructions to do this (and I'm new to Linux/Git).

I am using msysgit, and for the most part I'm fine with deploying entire repositories but in many cases it is much more efficient to deploy small fixes a few files at a time.

Pushing/pulling/installing git on the remote servers isn't really an option as my level of access varies between projects and clients.

Is there a straight-forward way to (rough guess):

```
pipe 'diff --names-only' to 'git-archive'?
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to involve git-archive. Using `--name-only`, you could tar up the files:

```
tar czf new-files.tar.gz `git diff --name-only [diff options]`
```

Since you're new to Linux, this might need some explanation:

The backticks in the command line cause the shell to first execute the command within the backticks, then substitute the output of that command into the command line of `tar`. So the `git diff` is run first, which generates a list of filenames, one on each line. The newlines are collapsed to spaces and the whole list of files is placed on the `tar` command line. Then `tar` is run to create the given archive. Note that this can generate quite long command lines, so if you have a very large number of changed files you may need a different technique.

Comment: Just for posterities sake, that different technique would be something like: `git diff --name-only [diff options] | xargs tar -czf files.tar.gz`

Comment: With `xargs`, you have a different problem because `xargs` will run `tar` more than once if there are too many files to put them all on a single command line. This will cause `tar` to create a new .tar file overwriting the previous one, so it will only contain the files for the last batch.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the syntax! The backticks are what I needed :)  This works perfectly in bash commandline that comes with msysgit except where there are spaces in filenames (windows...). Is there a way to escape them automatically?

Comment: Greg, that can easily be fixed by using `-rvf` instead of `-cvf` as arguments to `tar`.

Comment: @jason: Good idea. You'd have to add a second step to compress the archive later, because -r only works on uncompressed archives.

Comment: Right, hence why I left the compressing off there. I'm not sure why, but adding `v` is so deeply ingraned in my muscle memory when taring/untaring things.

Comment: Using zip you can archive and compress in one go: `git diff -–name-only commit1 commit2 | zip changes.zip –@`. If you use UnxTools or cygwin this will work on windows too.

Comment: How would you make a diff ignoring files which only has modified permissions?

Comment: @GregHewgill My option: `git diff -z --name-only [diff options] | tar cz --files-from - --null -f files.tar.gz`

Comment: I believe that --name-only will give you files that have been deleted as well. Which could lead to an error when zipping or empty files inside the zip. The option --name-status will do the same as --name-only except add an M,D or A to the front. Some more clever parsing using this idea is probably optimal.

Comment: I'd advise using `git diff --diff-filter=AM […]`, so only **a**dded or **m**odified files are listed in the git-diff output. No need for extra parsing.