# Create package of latest revisions in Github

Tags: version-control, github, patch

I have looked for the 'patch' system but I don't think this is what I want. I've also done a little research but I am not sure how I should ask the question.

I want to make a package with only the modified files of the latest revisions on Github.

I am wondering if there's a little application or some sort of commands I could use instead of going into each revisions and track files by files which have been modified to then pack them all into a zip/tar.gz file.

Reason we want to do this is obviously update a lot of websites using an older version, without having the trouble to go look up for each files that we're modified and pack them 'by hand'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this might help? [Exporting / Archiving changed files only in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678032/exporting-archiving-changed-files-only-in-git)

Looks like a similar issue if I understand what you are trying to do!