# Git: retrieve specific commit

Tags: git, export, commit

I need to export to an archive a set of commits in a git repository.
How do I do this?
Using svn, I could choose commits and export to zip.

Comment: you mean export diffs of these commits?

Comment: Yeah sorry now I realize it wasn't easy to understand.
I need an archive with most update files between 2 commits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To export the repository up to a certain commit:

`git archive -o export.zip <COMMIT>`. Replace `<COMMIT>` with the commit number you want to export.

To create a patch between two commits:

`git diff COMMIT1 COMMIT2 > patch.txt`

Comment: I though this command would export every commit in the repository until the specified commit is found.
I need to export the specified commit(s) only. Just like a patch.

Comment: ok... But a patch is for use into another repository. 
It contains markup to understand where modifications has been made.
I need an archive with only the modified (up to date) files between specified commits.

Comment: So you want an export of some specific files valid at a certain commit number?

Comment: That's correct.
Let's suppose I run a website and I just commited some modifications to the repository. Now to deploy my modifications, I need an archive containing just the modified files between last commit and previous commit.
I appreciate your patience :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678032/exporting-archiving-changed-files-only-in-git

Comment: @user1170896 You can use `patch -p1 < patch.txt` to deploy the modifications.

Answer (score 10):

Git has a handy way of creating a patch for each commit. Although this originally was meant as a way to format patches so that they can be sent through email, they are a handy way of extracting a set of changes.

The command you want is `git format-patch` and the way you apply these formatted patches back into git is with the `git am` command.

For example if you you have two commits C1 and Cn that you want to export as a set of git patches you only need:

```
git format-patch -k C1..Cn
```

This will create a set of numbered patches (in your current directory). Each patch will be a diff of the commit, as well as the commit information (Title, comment, author, date, etc).

This is a lot more than a simple diff file between two commits will provide you.

Comment: I think this needs to be `git format-patch -k C1~..Cn` instead of `git format-patch -k C1..Cn`, because the left side of the range is _exclusive_, so you have to give the _parent_ (`~`) of the first commit.