# Using Git to create an archive of changed files

Tags: git

I am looking for a simple solution to make a archive of recent changed file.

I get this simple command from [google](http://tosbourn.com/2011/05/git/using-git-to-create-an-archive-of-changed-files/)

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)
```

When I run it in GIT BUSH, it keeps saying saying
**fatal: Not a valid object name**

Comment: Which command does that come from? (What's the output of `git diff --name-only HEAD^`? You're in a valid repository, right?)

Comment: git diff --name-only HEAD^ will output a list of changed file which I would like to archive. I have tested this command with a test repository, it works as exptected. It doesn't work in my real asp.net project repository

Comment: I suspect, there are some can't archive? binary?

Comment: `git-archive` will archive any files - they're just blobs of data to it. The only two object names here are `HEAD` and `HEAD^`. I was trying to get you to check to make sure both of those are valid object names in the repository you're running the command in. For example, maybe it only has one commit in it, so `HEAD^` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I have copy and paste the project file to a new folder, commit a changes and use the above command to archive. It works as expected.

Comment: What is HEAD and HEAD^? I have assumed that HEAD is a current MASTER, HEAD^ is the last commit

Comment: HEAD is "where you are now" (whatever commit you're on, usually the tip of the current branch but if you're in a "detached HEAD" state, it's just "the commit you're on").  HEAD^ is "starting from the commit you're on, go back one commit, i.e., to whatever commit `git log` shows as its parent."  (In the case of a merge commit there can be more than one parent; HEAD^ picks "the first one", and there's more syntax for naming the others.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting / Archiving changed files only in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678032/exporting-archiving-changed-files-only-in-git)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678032/exporting-archiving-changed-files-only-in-git) in that case that tells me to

```
tar czf changed-files.tar.gz `git diff --name-only [diff options]`
```

For example, to create an archive containing the files changed in the last four revisions, I'd do

```
tar czf changed-files.tar.gz `git diff --name-only HEAD~4..`
```

This assumes – of course – that `HEAD~4` does actually exist.

Comment: eckes,Thank you to point out that the HEAD can use in this way.

Comment: -1: This solution only works if the files within the diff exist at HEAD, regardless of what commit you choose.

Comment: WARNING : This solution shows *CHANGED* files only. If you have new files, this solution skips them. Using 'git status -s' or something like that will pick up added files as well.

Answer (score 4):

I use this alias to include new files not in HEAD:

```
alias gittar='tar -czvf working-files.tgz \
              $(git status -s | sed -r "s/..(.*)/\1 /")'
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to filter out files deleted while that diff to fix that error:

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD^..HEAD)
```

May be `git archive` is overhead for that task and you should use [@eckes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10023894/2110496).
But, you still should add `--diff-filter=d` to exclude removed files from archive.