# Git - pull only changed files into a separate folder

Tags: git, pull

Situation: I would like to do a git pull, but then the new files have to be moved to an offline machine.

The question is: Is it possible to download into a new folder only the files that are changed since the current commit? If it would keep the folder structure, that also would be awesome!

Comment: you can try this https://tosbourn.com/using-git-to-create-an-archive-of-changed-files/

Comment: This sounds very confusing. :/

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678056/7976758) better?

Comment: Would it be a solution to use a folder on a memory stick as remote for the offline machine? You could git pull, copy the repo to the stick, stick it into the offline machine and git pull from the stick?

Comment: Wao, I've never though about this, but if we could manage to make the pendrive accessable with high-speed as it would be a webapplication, this might work out.

Comment: phd: Sounds better, yes. Testing it now

Answer (score 2):

You could write a shell script to do it.

Assuming you are on the `master` branch and your changes live on the `origin` remote:

1. Get the latest changes with `git fetch origin`
2. Change your working directory to the latest changes: `git checkout origin/master`
3. Determine which files have changed with: `git diff --name-status master..origin/master`
4. Copy those files to a new folder
5. Go back to your original branch: `git checkout master`

Comment: Why creating a temporary branch? Step 2 could be simplified to `git checkout origin/master` (which just creates a detached HEAD).

Comment: You are absolutely right, just habit I guess. Edited my answer as a result, thanks!

Comment: What if there are about 200 files? I can't just copy-paste them all (I mean I could, but seriousl). There must be an easier way.